# Append part of result into list in python

Tags: python

There is some method, which output two variables, for example:

```
def some_method():
    #some calculations
    return first_value, second_value
```

Now I want to put in one line results into variable and list (put `first_value` to some variable and `second_value` add to list as a new element).

I know that I can do something like this:

```
def some_method(list):
    #some calculations
    return first_value, list+[second_value]
```

and then:

```
some_variable, list = some_method(list)
```

but is there any chance to do it in one line and without pass list as method argument?

Comment: Firstly, it is not advisable to declare a variable with `list` as the name since this will override the builtin `list` class. Since, you want the contents of `list` to be updated with `second_value` then either you must pass this `list` as input to the function or you have to access the global values within the function. As list objects are passed as objects to functions, you can use `.append` function of a list to update with the latest element and this will be reflected in the module namespace also. With the usage of `.append`, you can simply return `first_value` from the function

Comment: @rogaos: the above thing is for small method which will be call many times within very complex simulation, so I'm looking for simple and short solution

Comment: @Nakamura: you are right, there is bad habit to use reserved names in examples (for example naming lists as 'list')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you return the second value in a list?

Like this:

```
>>> L = [1, 2, 3]
>>> def bar():
...     return 'shenanigan', [4]
... 
>>> myVar, L[len(L):] = bar()
>>> L
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

really, though, you might as well assign the second return value to an intermediate variable and just use list.append(), using two lines.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want it, you can subclass list and make something like this:

```
>>> def f():
...     return 1, 2

>>> class MyList(list):
...     def __setattr__(self, name, value):
...         if name == '_assign_append':
...             self.append(value)
... 

>>> l = MyList()

>>> a, l._assign_append = f()
>>> a
1
>>> l
[2]
>>> b, l._assign_append = f()
>>> a
1
>>> b
1
>>> l
[2, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a function decorator as follow to do it:

```
def remember_history(f):
    l = []
    def wrapper(*args,**kw):
        x,e = f(*args,**kw)
        l.append(e)
        return x,l
    return wrapper

def some_method():
    return 1,2

f = remember_history(some_method)
print f() # 1,[2]
print f() # 1,[2,2]
print f() # 1,[2,2,2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not without calling the function twice:

```
>>> L = []
>>> def foo():
...     return 1, 2
... 
>>> myvar, L = foo()[0], L+[foo()[1]] 
>>> myvar
1
>>> L
[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> L = []
>>> def foo():
...     return 1, 2
... 
>>> myvar, _ = tuple(process(i) for process, i in zip((lambda x: x, lambda x: L.append(x)), foo()))
>>> myvar
1
>>> L
[2]
```

This fulfills the requirement that it should be a one-liner, but it seems quite ugly to me.

I'd prefer the idea to use a decorator.